# Dynamics CRM workflow - prevent contemporary wait conditions on the same record

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

We have a wait condition of 5 days on a background workflow. If the workflow is triggered again on the same record before the 5 days period expires, we would like to stop the first wait condition, and only consider the new one. Is it possible, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding a "workflow execution counter" field to the entity, and modifying the workflow depending on the value of this field.